# Cookie working fine on localhost but not working on vercel production

Tags: vercel, setcookie, next.js13

I am setting a cookie in middleware:

```js
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const cookie = req.cookies.get("app_id")?.value;
  if (cookie) return NextResponse.next();

  const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers);
  const app_id: string | undefined = requestHeaders.get("host")?.split(".")[0];
  requestHeaders.set("app_id", app_id?.toString() || "");

  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
  response.cookies.set("app_id", app_id || "");
  return response;
}
```

Now I have a page in app directory in which I am using header and cookies from  next to get app_id, it works on localhost fine but not on vercel production.

Page Code:

```js
async function fetchMethod(category_id: string | number | boolean) {
  const url = "https:/rest_api";
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const header = headers();

  const app_id_cookie =
    cookieStore.get("app_id")?.value || header.get("Cookie")?.split("=")[1];
  console.log(app_id_cookie);
  const bodyData = `contact_id=&category=&timestamp=`;
  const response = await fetch(`${url}/?app_id=${app_id_cookie}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: bodyData,
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": " application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    cache: "force-cache",
  });
  return await response.json();
}
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: same. first time being frustrated while using vercel

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem Vercel causes...You must use "POST" request to access the log out endpoint. If you send "GET" request, It wont work. Hope this helps.